# Swift expression, empty or nonexistent dictionary in array - reliably zero?

Tags: swift, swift3, optional-variables

A String dictionary of arrays

```
blah: [String:[Stuff]]
```

For a given key, say "foo", I want to know how many items are in that array - but, if there is ***no such array***, I just want to get ***zero***.

I'm doing this ...

```
blah["foo"]?.count ?? 0
```

so

```
if ( (blah.down["foo"]?.count ?? 0) > 0) {
   print("some foos exist!!")
else {
   print("there are profoundly no foos")
}
```

**Am I correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct but you might find it easier to remove the optional *earlier*:

```
(blah["foo"] ?? []).count
```

or

```
if let array = blah.down["foo"], !array.isEmpty {
   print("some foos exist!!")
} else {
   print("there are profoundly no foos")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But I'd probably write it with optional binding, like:

```
if let c = blah.down["foo"]?.count, c > 0 {
   print("some foos exist!!")
}
else {
   print("there are profoundly no foos")
}
```